# HBase on AWS EMR slow to retrieve data

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, hbase, amazon-emr, happybase

I am running an AWS EMR cluster with HBase installed, I followed [these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hbase-create.html) for setting up the cluster using s3 as the Hbase datastore. The cluster is up and running and I am able to ssh in and use the `hbase shell` with no problems.

The data we are trying to store is genomic data and very wide. For each row-key, there can be up to 250,000 column keys. We have experimented with different numbers of column families, from grouping all the keys in 1 column family, to using 42 different column families with the column keys spread out amongst them.

To interact with Hbase, we are using `happybase` in python, which uses `thrift` to communicate with the primary node. When retrieving a single row-key, it takes around 2.7s to return the result. I was expecting ms data retrieval times for this type of operation. When retrieving. Our configuration is very simple with no additional optimizations done. We are trying to decide if Hbase is the right application for our database needs but given the slow data retrieval times, we are leaning away from it.

[image]

[image]

I am aware that other large industry players use HBase for their needs and was wondering if anyone knows what things we can try to optimize performance? While these times aren't terrible, the application will eventually need to put thousands of row-keys and retrieve thousands of row-keys for all columns. Given the scaling we have seen so far, it would be untenable for our needs.

I have minimal experience with distributed NoSQL technologies like HBase so any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Cluster setup:

```
1 Master node, 3 Core nodes
m4.large instances
```

Things we have tried:

1. Adjusting number of column families
2. Using HDFS instead of s3 as datastore

Comment: If each row can have up to 250k columns, are you aware how many columns/column families the specific row has that you are testing on? Since you are calling table.row() without specifying any columns, could there be a change that you are indeed retrieving hundreds of thousands of key values? Try calling table.row() with a specific column and see if that makes a difference. If the cluster is not busy you should expect single-digit or low double-digit MS response. Although I'm not sure how big is your data, as your cluster is pretty small with only 3 RS.

Comment: We have tried putting all 250k column keys into one family, as well as spreading them out over 42 column families. We are working with dog genetic data so 38 chromosomes but some other contigs and sex chromosomes. This grouping was logical. We get much better performance when grabbing 100-1000 columns but our use-case usually has us fetching up to 180k column keys or more. The data is quite small, each cell value is just a diploid genotype, "AA" for instance

Comment: 42 column families is definitely an overkill, as I think the docs suggest 2-3 families max. If you have to return circa 180k columns per row with each Get, then maybe it's worth considering adding a lot more data into one cell and having some internal structure within the cell, for example in Json format. Another approach could be to have longer rows and more structure within the rowKey. This way, perhaps you can use Scans instead of Gets.

Comment: @VS_FF, thank you for your suggestion. We went ahead and implemented it. Essentially, what we did was pack a bunch of cells into a byte string, so instead of 250,000 column keys, each mapping to a small two-char string, we created 42 column keys with the bytes concatenated into a big string. The length of each cell is fixed so we were easily able to create an index from the previous cell -> value to the new value[index]. Do you have any other suggestions or best practices for hbase performance?

Comment: Glad you are getting better performance this way. HBase has a myriad of settings and best practices. It's hard to suggest something proactively without knowing what the problem is. I'd strongly suggest at least skimming through the official HBase Guide. It's a bit long, but very useful: https://hbase.apache.org/book.html